# Debugging of javascript in Textmate

Tags: javascript, textmate

How shall I do for jumping to definition of function of javascript in Textmate? 
Does Textmate support intergated debugging for javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out [Firebug for Textmate](http://doctyper.com/archives/200703/firebug-bundle-for-textmate/)? It supports debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's not solving your problem, but might help - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210408114313/http://www.cocoabits.com/TmCodeBrowser/)